# CSS transition/animation : rotate on hover effect

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

So I have this arrow that rotates when the `.collapse` class is applied:

[image] then [image]

The css is:

```
.my-arrow {
  background: url('arrow.svg');
  transition: transform ease 0.2s;
  transform: rotate(0deg);

  &.collapse {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

I also wanted to add a hover effect, for better user feedback.

But if I add:

```
.my-arrow {
  &:hover {
    rotate(90deg);
  }
  &.collapse {
    &:hover {
      rotate(0deg);
    }
  }
}
```

It works on hover, but when I click (= add the `.collapse` class), it rotates back to `0deg`, because the mouse is still hovering the div, which is even more confusing.

Is there any way to tackle this issue? I guess I could do this is JS with an extra class that would toggle `onmouseleave`, but this is way too complicated for my use case.

I tried with CSS animations:

```
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}


@keyframes rotate-back {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
.my-arrow {
  &:hover {
    animation: rotate .2s ease 1;
  }

  .collapse {
    &:hover {
      animation: rotate-back .2s ease 1;
    }
  }
```

without success, and I'm very n00b in CSS animations. Maybe with a delay?

Cheers

Comment: `.my-arrow {
  &:hover,&.collapse {
    rotate(90deg);
  }
}` ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hover-rotate{
  transition: transform .3s; /* Apply the transition property. Enables the animation */
}
.hover-rotate:hover{
  transform: rotate(90deg); /* Rotate if mouse is hovered */
}
.hover-rotate.collapse{
  transform: rotate(90deg); /* Rotate if collapse class is present */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="hover-rotate fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
```

You can use the CSS transition property to make this animation. The above code animates if either mouse hovers over the icon or the class `.collapse` is applied.