# How do i make the ">" symbol rotate to the face downwards in HTML and CSS when hovering over it?

Tags: html, css

I have been programming a replica of a Coca-Cola website for an assignment and I want to make the symbol rotate downwards when I hover over it.

Everything else works just fine and there are no links as they are placeholders for the moment, I have scoured most of the internet and haven't actually found a solution yet. Please anyone help!

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.navtopbar {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navtopbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
}

.navtopbar li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navtopbar li a {
  color: black;
  display: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navtopbar ul ul{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.navtopbar ul ul li{
  display: block;
}
.navtopbar li:hover ul{
  display: block;
}
.navtopbar ul ul li a:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navtopbar a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Navigation bar buttons-->

<!-- allows CSS to style the entire list-->

<ul>
  <li><a><img src="" width=" height="20"></a></li>
  <li><a href="placeholder">Brands</a></li>
  <li><a href="placeholder">Discover > </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="placeholder">Coca Cola App</a></li>
      <li><a href="placeholder">Coke Creations</a></li>
      <li><a href="placeholder">Fanta Halloween</a></li>
      <li><a href="placeholder">Coca Cola Football Promotion</a></li>
      <li><a href="placeholder">Sprite Heat Hacks</a></li>
      <li><a href="placeholder">Diet Coke What you Love</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="placeholder">Impact ></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="placeholder">Sustainability</a></li>
      <li><a href="placeholder">Social</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Have looked online and haven't found anything and no idea how to actually do this

Comment: Does this answer your question [CSS transition/animation : rotate on hover effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66885144/css-transition-animation-rotate-on-hover-effect)?

Comment: Don't use a greater than symbol as an arrow. It has its own meaning. It would be particularly confusing to screen reader users. Use an `<img>` or `<svg>` then rotate it with CSS.

Comment: It would also need to be in it's own element (perhaps a `span`) which can then be rotated.

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked your code a little bit for you - added an element to contain your chevron and applied a simple CSS class to it:

CSS:

```
.rotary{
 display: inline-block;
}

a:hover .rotary{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="placeholder">Discover <span class="rotary"> > </span> </a>
```

https://codepen.io/Isonimus/pen/oNmxZoP

Anyway, you should use something other than the chevron for this purpose, as it can and will be annoying for screen reader users.